# NotifyDataSetChanged is not refreshing the ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I am working on ViewPager Concept. In ViewPager item cell contains two items such as ImageView and TextView.

Initially, i will download Blur Image and show in ViewPager cell. After this was completed, i will download HighResolution Image and show in ViewPager cell respectively.

For example, if i am looking at the first Item in ViewPager as Blur Image and in background it is downloading HighResolution image and then it must refresh the ViewPager and show the HighResolution Image in the respectively view cell.

After swiping two items and then back to the first Item, that time it shows the High Resolution Image.

So my issue is without swiping left or right, i need to refresh the current view if any changes happened in the current view.

ViewPager Activity Class:

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends Activity {
ViewPager pager;
String[] _blurImageURL;

PagerAdapter _pagerAdapter;
Context _context;

ViewPagerModel vpModel = new ViewPagerModel();

ArrayList<String> lstQueue=new ArrayList<String>();
Handler _handler=new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerView);
    _context = this;

    _blurImageURL = new String[]{

            "http://cdn.connollyphoto.nyc/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/cp_seanbell_portrait_002-800x1200.jpg",
            "http://static.wixstatic.com/media/e6f301_7d57a9c0ebdf4d438f88633637aaed77.jpg_srz_930_1395_85_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srz",
            "http://a4.format-assets.com/image/private/s--TmkImGBO--/c_limit,g_center,h_1200,w_65535/a_auto,fl_keep_iptc.progressive,q_95/31336-7293530-portrait-1_jpg2.jpg",
            "http://daviddodgephotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Donna_12.jpg",
            "http://a3.format-assets.com/image/private/s--W9Flct-g--/c_limit,g_center,h_1200,w_65535/a_auto,fl_keep_iptc.progressive,q_95/173355-8951465-Marvin_Portraits-005.jpg",
            "http://www.leifnorman.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/IMG_6070.jpg",
            "https://dwaynefoong.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/amin-fashion-portrait-dwayne-foong-photography.jpg",
            "https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/117495331/hd/ce856c4a1fb4c09a5ecec05839f6ddc4.jpg",
            "http://www.pcimagenetwork.com/perks/Perks%202013.jpg",
    };


    _pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(_context, vpModel, this);
    pager.setAdapter(_pagerAdapter);

    // Calling Volley Library to Download the Image for each URLi

    for (int i = 0; i < _blurImageURL.length; i++) {
        String fileName = String.valueOf(i);
        fileName=fileName+"_blurImg";

        DownloadImages(_blurImageURL[i], fileName, true);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_pager, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void updateView() {
    _pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 public void DownloadQueue(String url_in,String fileName_in)
 {
     if(lstQueue.contains(fileName_in))
     {
         Log.i("Duplicate_Request=",fileName_in);
     }
     else{
         lstQueue.add(fileName_in);
         DownloadImages(url_in,fileName_in,false);
     }

 }

void DownloadImages(String imageURL_in, final String fileName_in, final boolean isBlur_in) {
    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(imageURL_in,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {
                    try {
                        Log.v("Response_Received =",fileName_in);
                        // Saved in SD Card and getting the Path
                        String imagePath = SavedInSDCard(response,fileName_in);

                        //updating the Model
                        if (isBlur_in) {
                            vpModel.blurImgLocalPath.add(imagePath);

                        } else {
                            vpModel.highResolutionImgLocalPath.add(imagePath);
                        }

                          //updating the View
                        _handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run () {
                                updateView();
                            }
                        });  


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 0, null, null);
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(imageRequest);

}

public String SavedInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName_in) {

    File dir = new File(ApplicationController.getAppContext()
            .getExternalFilesDir("ViewPager_POC") + "/Cache");
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(dir, fileName_in);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String imgPath = dir + "/" + fileName_in;
    return imgPath;
}


}
```

ViewPager Adapter Class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context _context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewPagerActivity _vpActivity;

String[] _highResolutionURL = new String[]{
        "http://www.monportraitpro.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Philippe-Vasilescu.jpg",
        "http://www.markhicksphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/MHP2012_01_04_MHP_DSC0003.jpg",
        "http://www.andrew-mason.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/portrait-1-3.jpg",
        "http://shutterfinger.typepad.com/.a/6a00e551a6244a8833019affd0eb14970d-pi",
        "http://www.antonioolmos.com/data/photos/90_1childs_livebooks.jpg",
        "http://www.dvdsreleasedates.com/pictures/800/12000/Zachary-Quinto.jpg",
        "http://www.glnphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/IMG_1347.jpg",
        "http://www.dvdsreleasedates.com/pictures/800/12000/Paul-Walker.jpg",
        "http://www.antonioolmos.com/data/photos/89_1blairbooks.jpg",
};

ArrayList<String> _blurImgPath;
ArrayList<String> _highResolutionImgPath;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context_in, ViewPagerModel vpModel_in, ViewPagerActivity activity_in) {
    _context = context_in;
    _blurImgPath = vpModel_in.blurImgLocalPath;
    _highResolutionImgPath = vpModel_in.highResolutionImgLocalPath;
    _vpActivity = activity_in;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _blurImgPath.size();
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtCounter;
    final ImageView imgView;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container,
            false);

    txtCounter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);


    imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.images);

    //Setting the values for Image and textview
    txtCounter.setText("" + (position + 1));

    //Setting the Image
    if (position < _highResolutionImgPath.size()) {
        //Setting Hi-ResImage
        Log.v("HighRes_ImgPath=", "Get Image from Model" );
        imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_highResolutionImgPath.get(position)));
    } else {
        // Generating the request for HighResolution Image
        String fileName = String.valueOf(position + 10);
        fileName = fileName + "_clearImg";

        Log.v("HighRes_ImgPath=", "Sending Request to Queue=" + fileName);
        _vpActivity.DownloadQueue(_highResolutionURL[position], fileName);
        //Setting the BlurImage
        imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_blurImgPath.get(position)));

    }


    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

}
```

ViewPager Model:

```
public class ViewPagerModel {

ArrayList<String> blurImgLocalPath=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> highResolutionImgLocalPath=new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

activity_view_pager.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.poc_viewpager.ViewPagerActivity" >

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pagerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

/>
```

view_pager_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="43dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) :

For example :

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(URL_THUMBNAIL) // thumbnail url goes here

                        .into(IMAGEVIEW, new Callback() { // Your image view

                            // On success start loading the full resolution image
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {       

                                Picasso.with(getActivity())

                                        .load(FULL_RESOLUTION_URL) // image url goes here
                                        .into(IMAGEVIEW);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                // Manage downloading errors here
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `updateView()`is called on the background thread. `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work on the background thread. Call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the UI thread and it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @Alim Parker for suggestion. But it is not worked for me . Still View is not updating.